# How to send UID value from GPS service to next class public void onLocationChanged Android

Tags: java, android, gps

We are working on logistics app on Android. App will start independent GPS service that is sending location on change to web server (Apache). GPS service starts with  UID and Android Studio log shows that GPS service has this UID working. The problem is that lat and long values are coming to server corretly but UID is simple "0". How can we make GPS service to send UID correctly to server?

Here is the code as it is working right now:

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class MyService extends Service
{
    private static final String TAG = "BOOMBOOMTESTGPS";
    private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
    private static String UID = null;
    private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 5000;
    private static final float LOCATION_DISTANCE = 10f; // 10f


    private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener // private // public
    {
        Location mLastLocation;
        //public String UID;


        public LocationListener(String provider)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
            mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
        }



        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location);
            mLastLocation.set(location);

            //Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);

            HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();

            data.put("id", UID); // SIIN SOOVIN KÄTTE SAADA VÄÄRTUST!!!!
            //data.put("id2", iddata);
            data.put("lat", Double.toString(location.getLatitude()));
            data.put("lng", Double.toString(location.getLongitude()));

            AsyncHttpPost asyncHttpPost = new AsyncHttpPost(data);
            asyncHttpPost.setListener(new AsyncHttpPost.Listener(){
                @Override
                public void onResult(String result) {
                    // do something, using return value from network
                }
            });
            asyncHttpPost.execute("https://www.isekallur.ee/android/read_gps2.php");

            Log.e(TAG, "DATA: " + data);

        }

       // private void postText(){

        //}

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider);
        }
    }

    LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[] {
            new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),
            new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
    };

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    /*@Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        String myID = intent.getExtras().getString("USER_ID");
    }*/

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        String iddata =(String) intent.getExtras().get("USER_ID");

        final String UID = intent.getStringExtra("USER_ID");
        //doSomething2(UID);

        Log.e(TAG, "UID: " + UID + " - " + iddata);
        //postID(UID);

        return START_STICKY; // START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY  // START_STICKY
    }

    /*private void postID(String UID){
        Log.e(TAG, "UID2: " + UID);

    }*/

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {

        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");
        initializeLocationManager();
        try {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                    mLocationListeners[1]);
        } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
            Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        try {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                    mLocationListeners[0]);
        } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
            Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "gps provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mLocationManager != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mLocationListeners.length; i++) {
                try {
                    mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListeners[i]);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "fail to remove location listners, ignore", ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void initializeLocationManager() {
        Log.e(TAG, "initializeLocationManager");
        if (mLocationManager == null) {
            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        }
    }

}
```